# Call ASMX web service from Javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services

I have built an asmx web service that reads from a local sql database which I  want to connect to my web application. I have already added a service reference, the only issue is I do not know how to call the web service in my web application directly.

Here is part of my asmx web service:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="PostWebService" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class PostWebService  : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    //method to get heart rates from sql database
    [WebMethod]
    public List<int> GetHeartRates() {
        var heartRate = new List<int>();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (local); Initial Catalog =  RatesDB; Integrated Security=True"))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" select HeartRate from Rates", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    heartRate.Add((int)rdr[0]);
                }
                rdr.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return heartRate;
    }
```

Here is part of my .aspx web page

```
    <html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['gauge']
      });

       d3.csv("brT16.csv", function (rrdata) {
           d3.csv("hrT16.csv", function (hrdata) {
                   for (var i = 0; i < rrdata.length; i++) {
                       for (var j = 0; j < hrdata.length; j++) {
                               console.log(rrdata[i]);
                               console.log(hrdata[j]);
                       }
               }

                   count = 0;
                   count2 = 0;
                   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                   function drawChart() {

                       // respiration gauge
                       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                           ['Label', 'Value'],
                           ['RR', 0],
                           //['Heart Rate', 0],
                       ]);

                       var options = {
                           width: 600,
                           height: 250,
                           redFrom: 35,
                           redTo: 55,
                           yellowFrom: 25,
                           yellowTo: 35,
                           minorTicks: 5,
                           max: 50,
                       };

                       var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

                       chart.draw(data, options);

                       setInterval(function () {
                           data.setValue(0, 1, parseInt(rrdata[count][0]));
                           chart.draw(data, options);
                           count++;
                       }, 1000);
```

I want to call the web service directly so that it reads from the sql database instead of the csv. Any tips in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery?  You can look at this post.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285870/calling-asmx-web-service-from-javascript

Comment: I looked at the post but don't see how would I call the web service in the graph so that it reads the values from there, unless i am completely overlooking it

Answer (score 0):

When adding Reference to web-service make sure you are clicking advance button and adding web Reference(Advance -> Add Web Reference -> paste Url -> Add reference). You should be able to call web service methods after that.

Comment: I did add a web reference but i do not know the exact syntax for calling the web service

Comment: if you are calling from JavaScript try JQuery.Ajax() make sure datatype matches. else you should be able to call that method directly in backend code when you add using namespace.

Comment: i tried adding the jquery.ajax method, but whenever i did it and ran the web page, the chart isn't even visible anymore. Also, if i do successfully call the web service, how would i call the specific method that i want in that web service?

Comment: in Ajax method  call something like this url:"someUrl.com/GetHeartRate". if you have parameters pass it using  data: "{'TransactionID': '" + transactionId + "'}"

Comment: how can I call the ajax() method to call the web service without it messing up the graph? I placed it in my code but it made the graph no longer visible.